# Difference between SQL Server codes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a school assignment, I have to create a database and run reports. I've created code and a classmate has also created code and it runs the same thing, but his is in a format I've not seen and don't quite understand.

Here is mine:

```
SELECT
    Course.Name AS 'Course Name', 
    Program.Name AS 'Program Name'
FROM
    Course, Program, ProgramCourse
WHERE 
    ProgramCourse.CourseID = Course.ID
AND
    ProgramCourse.ProgramID = Program.ID
GO
```

And here's his:

```
CREATE VIEW NumberOfCoursePerProgram AS
        SELECT
                p.name AS ProgramName,  
                c.name AS CourseName
        FROM
                Program p
        JOIN
                ProgramCourse pc ON pc.ProgramID = p.ID
        JOIN 
                Course c ON c.ID = pc.CourseID
GO
```

I ran both queries using the data in the tables I've created. They return practically the same results, just in a slightly different order but it fulfills the assignment question. Anyway, if I delete the `p` from `Program p` from his code, it returns an error

> The multi-part identifier "p.name" could not be bound.

So how is SQL Server able to accept `p.name` and `p.ID`, etc. when I haven't ever established these variables? I don't quite understand how the code is working on his. Mine seems simple and straightforward, and I definitely understand what's going on there. So can someone explain his?

Thanks

Comment: And they should return the same results.  Specifying the join criteria in the where clause is exactly the same as in the join clause.  Using a JOIN clause (as opposed to doing it in the where clause) is from a new ANSI SQL standard, and some folks consider it preferable, but they will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a few differences.  First off, he's creating a `VIEW` rather than *just* a select statement:

```
CREATE VIEW NumberOfCoursePerProgram AS
```

Once the view is created, you can query the view just as you would a table:

```
SELECT * FROM NumberOfCoursePerProgram;
```

Second, he's using an ANSI JOIN rather than an implicit JOIN.  His method is more modern and most likely considered more *correct* by today's standards:

```
JOIN ProgramCourse pc ON pc.ProgramID = p.ID
JOIN Course c ON c.ID= pc.CourseID
```

Rather than:

```
FROM Course, Program, ProgramCourse
```

Also, note he's assigning [table aliases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) when he refers to a table:

```
FROM Program p
```

The `p` at the end allows you to substitute `p` rather than specify the entire table name of `Program` elsewhere in the query.  For example, you can now say `WHERE p.Foo > 5` rather than `WHERE Program.Foo > 5`.  In this case, it's just a shortcut and saves a few characters.  However, suppose you were referring to the same table twice (for example, JOINing in two different rows on the same table).  In that case, you might *have* to provide aliases for each table to disambiguate which one is which.

Comment: Obligatory [table alias documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). Also, though it doesn't look like a huge thing in this query, when you get in to cross-schema/cross-database queries, aliases are very helpful. Also, if you bring in a table more than once (e.g. `Address` table being joined by `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress` FK's) `JOIN Address shipaddr ON ...` & `JOIN Address billaddr ON ...`.

Comment: @BradChristie - Added in the link, thanks!  Good point on the cross-database queries.  I also added a blurb about join'ing in the same table twice, which as you said, would *require* aliases to avoid column ambiguity.  Good comments.

Comment: I forgot to mention that mine is also a view, I just forgot to include it when pasting on here. Oops.

Comment: @HanH1113 - Ah yea that makes sense.  I figured you *had* to know what a `VIEW` was since you ran his query after all :)

Answer (score 4):

These are called [alias](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) in SQL. Alias is basically created to give more readability and for better ease of writing code.

> The readability of a SELECT statement can be improved by giving a
> table an alias, also known as a correlation name or range variable. A
> table alias can be assigned either with or without the AS keyword:
>
> - table_name AS table alias
> - table_name table_alias

So in your query `p` is an alias to `Program` so that means now you can refer your table `Program` by the name of `p` instead of writing the whole name `Program` everywhere.

Similarly you can access the names of the columns of your table Program by simply writing p with a dot and then the column name. Something like `p.column`. This technique is very useful when you using **JOINS** and some your tables have similar names of the columns.

**EDIT:-**

Although most of the points are covered in other's answer. I am just adding a point that you should avoid the habit of JOINING table the way you are doing it right now.

You may check

## [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

by Aaron Bertrand for reference.

Comment: So I have a different table called `School` and if I used `FROM School s` and there's a column called `ID`, I could refer to that column of that table as `s.ID`?

Comment: Yes you can but do ensure that you have properly used the JOINS!

Comment: Also to make a point that the way you are JOINING your tables is obsolete now. It was used in 1990's. Your friend is using the better method which is now world widely accepted and used!

Comment: That's a great link, thanks. I just understand the concept of old-style joins better. It makes more sense in my head. 

Is there a good way of explaining on the new style joins work? I try to imagine it in my head but it gets fuzzy, therefore, I don't use it as often.

Comment: @HanH1113: You can check this link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/ and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @HanH1113 - You'll eventually have to get used to the ANSI JOIN syntax once you get into various *types* of JOINs.  Might as well get into the habit now.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW NumberOfCoursePerProgram AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
                p.name AS ProgramName,  
                c.name AS CourseName
        FROM
                Program p
        JOIN
                ProgramCourse pc ON pc.ProgramID= p.ID
        JOIN Course c ON c.ID= pc.CourseID
    END

GO
```

Observe that both tables `Program` and `Course` have a table alias defined.

The select part must specify the table from which the column name comes from. Which is exactly what you did. Your partner just added aliases to the tables names. These aliases are shorter, and makes the query look a bit less like a big wall of text.

The other difference is the use of joints. The joins are usually used to link results from two tables that has a corresponding column.

The columns are usually the primary key, and the foreign key in the second table.

Your query is fine, but the join syntax is preferred.

Edit : Once the view is created, it is now compiled and can be used in a select just like a table.

```
SELECT * FROM NumberOfCoursePerProgram
```

If you need to modify the view, you can use

```
ALTER VIEW NumberOfCoursePerProgram AS 
......
......
```

Comment: It's a `JOIN` - not a joint - that's your knee and elbow... and **no**, a view is **NOT** compiled... it's just a "compound" SQL statement that's expanded every time you select from it.

Comment: Thanks marc_s ! I think the joint thing comes from the fact that I often says Jointures (french)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can give a table an alias without AS, its optional.

If you were to add the AS it would will work just like you have it.

It may also be worthy to note that he is using a join as opposed to a where clause join, which is my preference because it's easier to read and more update code ethic.

Sometimes you need to join on a WHERE clause because of multiple conditions on join, but that's pretty rare in your case.

Comment: Thanks! I just prefer the Where clause because it's what I was exposed to first and it also makes more sense in my head. Is there a specific way of thinking I should adapt to with Join clauses?

Comment: Even if you have multiple conditions, you can use those in the **join condition** (no need to move those to the `WHERE` clause and make things confusing....)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here:

> if I delete the "p" from "Program p" from his code, it returns "The multi-part identifier "p.name" could not be bound."

The `P` is an alias for `program`. By doing it that way. If you ever need to use `Program` you can just call it `P`.

As far as what he is doing: it's better to do a `JOIN` in this case as opposed to doing a multi-table `SELECT` that you are doing. In simple cases it doesn't really matter but what if course and program both had millions of rows. In your way you are basically selecting everything. By doing the join on `ProgramID` you are only getting those items in `ProgramCourse` that correspond to an entry in `Program` as well (tied together by `ID` and `CourseID`).

One more important note. You are doing a simple `SELECT` statement. In SQL there are objects called VIEWS that act as a virtual table. He can now do any time a `SELECT * FROM NumberOfCoursePerProgram` and he will never have to do any of the joins, and selects again.

Hope that helps...